# Get specific EXIF tag from HsExif.parseFileExif

Tags: haskell, jpeg, exif

I'm trying to get a specific tag (e.g. `dateTimeDigitized`) from `HsExif`.
[Documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsexif-0.6.0.5/docs/Graphics-HsExif.html) says I can do it using [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup) function.
Trying this:

```
img <- parseFileExif image
let time = lookup dateTimeDigitized img
```

leads to this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[(ExifTag, b0)]'
                with actual type `Either
                                    String (containers-0.5.0.0:Data.Map.Base.Map ExifTag ExifValue)'
    In the second argument of `lookup', namely `img'
    In the expression: lookup dateTimeDigitized img
    In an equation for `time': time = lookup dateTimeDigitized img
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty simple:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[(ExifTag, b0)]'
            with actual type `Either
                                String (containers-0.5.0.0:Data.Map.Base.Map ExifTag ExifValue)'
In the second argument of `lookup', namely `img'
```

This is telling you: the `lookup` function wants a value of type `[(ExifTag, b0)]` as second argument but you gave `Either String (...Map ExifTag ExifValue)`.

In fact the value returned by `parseFileExif` is **not** the list on which you can call `lookup`. It's an `Either String (...Map ExifTag ExifValue)`.
Also note that the documentation doesn't say that you can use `lookup` on the return value of `parseFileExif`. Only that you can use `lookup` in some way (which is obvious if you know what [`Either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Either) is) to obtain the field you want.

You have to use a `case` to extra the `Right` value. For example:

```
img <- parseFileExif image
let time = case img of
     Left errorMessage -> ... handle error
     Right value -> lookup dateTimeDigitized value
```

Note that, although the documentation of the package links to `Data.List.lookup` they probably mean `Data.Map.lookup` since the value is a `Map`.

Moreover note that `lookup` returns a `Maybe a`. So you probably want to use the `fromMaybe` function from `Data.Maybe`:

```
img <- parseFileExif image
let time = fromMaybe 0 $ case img of
     Left errorMessage -> ... handle error
     Right value -> lookup dateTimeDigitized value
```

or the *unsafe* `fromJust` function:

```
img <- parseFileExif image
let time = case img of
     Left errorMessage -> ... handle error
     Right value -> fromJust $ lookup dateTimeDigitized value
```

(again from the `Data.Maybe` module).

So the whole program would look like

```
import Data.Maybe(fromJust)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

main = do
    img <- parseFileExif image
    let time = case img of
            Left _ -> error "unable to parse data"
            Right val -> fromJust $ Map.lookup dateTimeDigitized val
```

Comment: Tried to wrap into the function `getTimeDigitized image = do
    img <- parseFileExif image
    case img of
        Right value -> return $ lookup dateTimeDigitized value
        Left msg -> return Nothing` and now getting `Couldn't match expected type `[(ExifTag, b0)]'
                with actual type `containers-0.5.0.0:Data.Map.Base.Map
                                    ExifTag ExifValue'
    In the second argument of `lookup', namely `value'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `lookup dateTimeDigitized value'
    In the expression: return $ lookup dateTimeDigitized value`

Comment: @Nokeya Please add the code you used and the error message to the question. They are pretty much unreadable in a comment. Anyway I believe the issue is that you are using the wrong lookup. You probably have to use this [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:lookup) which is defined for `Map`s.